# Displaying dicom image in iPad using ITK

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, dicom, itk

I would like to display a dicom image in iPad using ITK framework.

After searching a lot, I found that ITK can only be used to display a dicom image on iPad (iOS).

But I didn't find any reference, documentation or code snippet to get started.

PLEASE HELP..

Comment: Any one...
Please help..

Comment: Finally.... its Imebra... 
I converted the dicom image to jpg and displayed it.. :)

RELAXED...

Comment: Are you sure? what about 12/16-bit CT or MR?  You need to at least perform 'contrast' windowing before showing things as a JPG.

Comment: Hi @Manmay  can you tell me how you proceeded with Imebra. I am also troubling with the same issue you had. see my post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14642063/how-to-display-dicom-dcm-extension-files-in-a-view-on-iphone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

USE Imebra to convert dicom image to jpg...

and then display the resultant image... :)

Comment: This might not work if you are trying to render 12-bit or 16-bit dicom images, standard jpeg only supports 8-bit rendering.